# Using multiple classifiers in a Java program

Tags: java, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using Stanford named entity recognition system  to identify named entities in my queries.
I discover that  one of the classifier (english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz) identify Person named entity more than the other (english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz). While the second classifier identify Organization named entity more than the first classifier. 
The question is how do i modify my code to combine both the performance of 3class and 7class classifiers. I mean how to combine line 2 and 3.  Below is my program

```
public void main () {
    //String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
    String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
    AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions                                  (serializedClassifier);
    //String s5 = "Access Team Microsoft";
    String s5 = " Victor Vianu";
    String ans4 = classifier.classifyToString(s5);
    System.out.println(ans4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually rephrasing a common optimization problem for classification tasks. It is possible to combine inputs from different named entity recognizers, but it is very unlikely that you will be able to do this in code. In that case, you would in practice be writing rule sets to express the preference of one annotation over the other. Such rule sets can become very complex and are very difficult to maintain, even if you are using a specialized framework.

Normally, an additional classifier is trained using both inputs along with annotation performed by humans. This is called supervised machine learning. If you are interested in the topic, have a look at the Gate framework, which provides a relatively gentle (GUI and lots of documentation available) introduction into text engineering and machine learning. You may be interested in the section about setting up machine learning: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch19.html#x24-46100019.2

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to get the scores or confidence of the ner tagger (3class, 7class etc.) and select the results of one classifier or another based on this score, for each token that has been identified as an entity of a certain type.

You can do that by creating an e.g., 
     List> results3ClassClassifier = 3Class.classify(textWithInstances);

(you get the results of the 7Class classifier as well,)
then you can have access to the scores , for instance:

```
     for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : results3ClassClassifier) {
          Triple<Counter<Integer>, Counter<Integer>, TwoDimensionalCounter<Integer, String>> scoresPerClass =  3Class.printProbsDocument(sentence);
//take score corresponding to a tagged token 
//put that in a set of scores to get later max confidence
    }
```

THis will give you something like:

```
Victor  null    O=0.011843980924431554  PERSON=0.9836181561256115   DATE=1.8909193023530869E-6  LOCATION=9.292607205855801E-5   ORGANIZATION=0.004434710463296233   PERCENT=1.168471927873708E-6    MONEY=3.925377823223501E-6  TIME=3.241645549570373E-6
Vianu   null    O=0.0019172569594321069 PERSON=0.9933531725355365   DATE=8.384789134033624E-6   LOCATION=2.134536699512499E-4   ORGANIZATION=0.004496303036216309   PERCENT=1.6256270957396572E-6   MONEY=7.507677140678878E-6  TIME=2.2957054950451435E-6
```

for Victor Vianu (great researcher!) this is straightforward, but for less known entities, the fact that you can get the confidence is useful in practice.